# How do I assign ViewType to RecyclerView?

Tags: android

I have the BaseBall Team and the BasketBall Team Table.
I want to bring data from each of these two tables and show it to one RecycleView.

So I was going to designate ViewType, but there was an error.

I think there is no error if BaseBallTeam data goes into ViewType first, and if BasketBall Team data goes in first, there is an error.

The table contains data from players with the same name, so the results are unconditionally taken from each table.

What should I do?

It's MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    SearchView searchView;
    ApiInterface apiInterface;
    Adapter adapter;
    List<BaseBallInfo> baseBallInfoList;
    List<BasketBallInfo> basketBallInfoList;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                searchBaseBall(query);
                searchBasketBall(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void searchBaseBall(final String name) {
        apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<List<BaseBallInfo>> call = apiInterface.getBaseBallInfo(name);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<BaseBallInfo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<BaseBallInfo>> call, Response<List<BaseBallInfo>> response) {
                String a = String.valueOf(response.body().get(0).getName());
                String b = String.valueOf(response.body().get(0).getBatting_avg());
                Log.e("MainActivity", a);
                Log.e("MainActivity", b);

                baseBallInfoList = response.body();
                adapter = new Adapter(MainActivity.this, baseBallInfoList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<BaseBallInfo>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("ErrorMessage", t.toString());
            }
        });
    }

    private void searchBasketBall(final String name) {
        apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<List<BasketBallInfo>> call2 = apiInterface.getBasketBallInfo(name);
        call2.enqueue(new Callback<List<BasketBallInfo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<BasketBallInfo>> call, Response<List<BasketBallInfo>> response) {
                String a = String.valueOf(response.body().get(0).getName());
                String b = String.valueOf(response.body().get(0).getPos());
                Log.e("MainActivity", a);
                Log.e("MainActivity", b);

                basketBallInfoList = response.body();
                adapter = new Adapter(MainActivity.this, basketBallInfoList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<BasketBallInfo>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("ErrorMessage", t.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It's Adapter.

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List list;

    public Adapter(Context context, List list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(list.get(position) instanceof BaseBallInfo) {
            return 0;
        }

        return 1;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(this.getItemViewType(viewType) == 0) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_baseball, parent, false);
            BaseBallViewHolder holder = new BaseBallViewHolder(view);
            return holder;
        } else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_basketball, parent, false);
            BasketBallViewHolder holder = new BasketBallViewHolder(view);
            return holder;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        if(this.getItemViewType(position) == 0) {
            BaseBallInfo baseBallInfo = (BaseBallInfo)list.get(position);
            BaseBallViewHolder holder = (BaseBallViewHolder) viewHolder;
            holder.nameTextView.setText(baseBallInfo.getName());
            holder.battingTextView.setText(baseBallInfo.getBatting_avg());
        } else if(this.getItemViewType(position) == 1) {
            BasketBallInfo basketBallInfo = (BasketBallInfo)list.get(position);
            BasketBallViewHolder holder = (BasketBallViewHolder) viewHolder;
            holder.name2TextView.setText(basketBallInfo.getName());
            holder.positionTextView.setText(basketBallInfo.getPos());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "No Result", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public static class BaseBallViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView nameTextView, battingTextView;

        public BaseBallViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
            battingTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.battingTextView);
        }
    }

    public static class BasketBallViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView name2TextView, positionTextView;

        public BasketBallViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name2TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name2TextView);
            positionTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.positionTextView);
        }
    }
}
```

It's Error Log.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.recyclerviewprac01, PID: 7589
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.example.recyclerviewprac01.Adapter.getItemViewType(Adapter.java:28)
        at com.example.recyclerviewprac01.Adapter.onCreateViewHolder(Adapter.java:38)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7078)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6235)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3540)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24966)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24966)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7139)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24966)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7139)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:403)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24966)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7139)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24966)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7139)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24966)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7139)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:992)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24966)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3301)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2028)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2330)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1888)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8511)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Plz Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal of `getItemViewType` is to get the position of the item and provide an `int` value specifying the type of the item. So, the problem is that you always access to it in the `onCreateViewHolder` method.

Change the `if(this.getItemViewType(viewType) == 0)` to `if(viewType == 0)` to fix the problem. You are mistakenly passing the `viewType` itself instead of item position.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I just need to figure out how to show all the data from the two tables.

Comment: You should keep one list of items to be shown on the recycler view. every time `onQueryTextSubmit` is being called, clear the list and by receiving the response of each call, add the items to this list and call `notifyDatasetChange()` on the adapter.